# Problems for plotting the negative part of the solutions of a differential equation using Mathematica/Wolfram

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, physics

I solved a differential equation using math, of the form y'' +0.6 y + 0.333 x^4 y - x^2 y + 0.03/x^2 y = 0. The solution is purely numerical. The equation has no solutions from x = -1 to x= 1. This is to be expected. When I try to plot the negative part together with the positive part in the same graph, and a spacing involving the unsolved region, I can't. Unfortunately this type of question is not accepted in the Wolfram newsgroups. That's why I'm using the internet. I appreciate an answer.

An answer about the problem.

Comment: Unless you share any programming code, I would assume that https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this question

Answer (score 0):

Provide more information about the boundary conditions so we can help you

```
Clear["`*"]
s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + 0.6 y[x] + 0.333 x^4 y[x] - x^2 y[x] + 
     0.03/x^2 y[x] == 0, y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```